# External SSD with SATA to USB 3 not being recognized by MacBookAir M2 while with SATA to USB 2 is working fine

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, sata

The SSD:

- Samsung 850EVO 500GB (ExFat formatted)

The adapters:

- SATA to USB 3 type A (ICY BOX IB-AC603a-U3)
- SATA to USB 3 type A (Sabrent)
- SATA to USB 2 type A (ICY BOX IB-AC603)
- USB 3 type A to USB 3 type C (Sabrent)

The SSD works fine with all SATA to USB type A adapters when I connect it to my 2011 MacBookPro witch only has USB 2 type A ports.

It also works fine on my MacBookAir M2 when I use the SATA to USB 2 type A adapter in combination with the USB 3 type A to USB 3 type C adapter. But of course only with the speed of USB 2.

It is not even being recognized by my MacBookAir M2 as soon as I'm using the SATA to USB 3 type A adapter in combination with the USB 3 type A to USB 3 type C adapter. Not in Disk Utilities not in System Information.

In short:
SATA to USB(A) 3 -> USB(A) 3 to USB(C) -> MBA M2 = not being recognized.
SATA to USB(A) 2 -> USB(A) 3 to USB(C) -> MBA M2 = works fine but slow.
SATA to USB(A) 2 -> MBP 2011 = works fine but slow.

I've tried Disk Utilities's first Aid, different Macs and a few different adapters. It is every time the same. I can't get it to work on the MacBookAir M2 with USB 3. The disc is ExFat formatted, but that should not be a problem, as it is not even being recognized in Disk Utilities.

Has anyone experienced the same issue, or has any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Can you provide a link to USB 3 type A to USB 3 type C adaptor (Sabrent)? I can find [this one](http://sabrent.com/products/cb-ctus). There is no indication this one is USB 3. Might only be USB 2.

Comment: https://amzn.eu/d/6DzuDcc this is the product I've bought. I includes the USB 3 type A to USB 3 type C adaptor. I also tried different USB 3 type A to USB 3 type C adaptors. No luck :(

Comment: Does the power/activity light on the Sabrent adapter come on? My summary of your issue is that you have never had it working at USB3 speeds - only at USB2 connected to both Macs.  Can you test this with a more recent Intel based MBP (with USB3 ports) - so as to determine whether your issue is the USB2/3 or Intel/M2

Comment: Yes the indicator is on and flashes when it successfully connects. Today I could test it on the iMac (Retina 5K, 27 Zoll, 2019) whits has both, USB 3 type A and Thunderbolt / USB 3 type C ports. Connected to the USB 3 type A port it always worked at USB 3 speed. Connected to the USB 3 type C port the behavior is random. Sometimes it worked with USB 3 and sometimes only with USB 2 speed. It seems that the port is not every time identifying the adapters as USB 3 device and in that case it is downscaling to USB 2 speed :( And still, on my new MackBookAir M2 the SSD is not even recognized.